# Twitter login in android not working

Tags: android, twitter, oauth

when i am trying to login the twitter app in android it shows following  error in logcat.i am not able to launch the twitter through my application.please give me some solutions.

```
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639): Error creating consumer / provider
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639): oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: null
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:214)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:69)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity.initData(PrepareRequestTokenActivity.java:129)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity.onCreate(PrepareRequestTokenActivity.java:64)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthProvider.sendRequest(CommonsHttpOAuthProvider.java:64)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:177)
03-18 12:47:28.412: E/com.android.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4639):    ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Refer this link

http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-integrate-twitter-in-android.html

You get some idea from this link

and check strict Mode enable or not? If Not enable plz do enable

```
StrictMode.enableDefaults();
```

Answer (score 0):

i just solve this issue by adding a single line in my code.

> StrictMode.enableDefaults();

thanks all response.

Answer (score 0):

Google in its latest version of android OS has made it compulsory the execution of network related things or other heavy tasks on Asynch Task..so as to avoid `ANR` eror

Notice Main thread Exception
in Your Log Caused by: `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

This exception is because if this limitiation..

Try running your task in ASYNC task means call the instance of TWITTER in `doInBackground`.

```
public class LoginTwitter extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.


            // call your loginTwiter here (the way you are calling twitter AOUTH)

            return false;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {


        }


    }
```

call this class on some UI click where actually you are currently calling the TwitterLogin

```
  private View.OnClickListener  LoginTwitter=new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View paramView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new LoginTwitter().execute((Void) null);;

        }
    };
```